# Move Ball around screen. Accelerometer. Bounce too

Tags: android, accelerometer, move

I have to do an app in Android that moves a ball around the screen. I need to move the ball with the accelerometer.
I have this code but the ball go around the border and doesn't bounce.

```
    package com.example.test2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class test2 extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    CustomDrawableView mCustomDrawableView = null;
    ShapeDrawable mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
    public float xPosition, xAcceleration, xVelocity = 0.0f;
    public float yPosition, yAcceleration, yVelocity = 0.0f;
    public float xmax, ymax;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Bitmap mWood;
    private SensorManager sensorManager = null;
    public float frameTime = 0.666f;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set FullScreen & portrait
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        // Get a reference to a SensorManager
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

        mCustomDrawableView = new CustomDrawableView(this);
        setContentView(mCustomDrawableView);
        // setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Calculate Boundry
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        xmax = (float) display.getWidth() - 50;
        ymax = (float) display.getHeight() - 50;
    }

    // This method will update the UI on new sensor events
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        {
            if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) {
                // Set sensor values as acceleration
                yAcceleration = sensorEvent.values[1];
                xAcceleration = sensorEvent.values[2];
                updateBall();
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateBall() {

        // Calculate new speed
        xVelocity += (xAcceleration * frameTime);
        yVelocity += (yAcceleration * frameTime);

        // Calc distance travelled in that time
        float xS = (xVelocity / 2) * frameTime;
        float yS = (yVelocity / 2) * frameTime;

        // Add to position negative due to sensor
        // readings being opposite to what we want!
        xPosition -= xS;
        yPosition -= yS;

        if (xPosition > xmax) {
            xPosition = xmax;
        } else if (xPosition < 0) {
            xPosition = 0;
        }
        if (yPosition > ymax) {
            yPosition = ymax;
        } else if (yPosition < 0) {
            yPosition = 0;
        }
    }

    // I've chosen to not implement this method
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // Unregister the listener
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        super.onStop();
    }

    public class CustomDrawableView extends View {
        public CustomDrawableView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            Bitmap ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.ball);
            final int dstWidth = 50;
            final int dstHeight = 50;
            mBitmap = Bitmap
                    .createScaledBitmap(ball, dstWidth, dstHeight, true);
            mWood = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.wood);

        }

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            final Bitmap bitmap = mBitmap;
            canvas.drawBitmap(mWood, 0, 0, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, xPosition, yPosition, null);
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

How can I solve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to move it with the accelerometer, but you're registering an orientation sensor listener.  Register for the accelerometer instead.

Comment: I don't know how to implement it :S

Comment: Look for the line where you're registering for a listener for a sensor.  Its in your onCreate.  See the type of sensor you're asking for?  It's the wrong type.  Change it to TYPE_ACCELEROMETER.

Comment: If I change the sensor to ACCELEROMETER, the ball doesn't move.

Comment: Ok, so looking again-  you have no bouncing code at all.  Notice that when you hit xmax or ymax in updatePosition you're just setting the position to max.  Instead you need to reverse its velocity for a little while. Same for when it hits the 0 position.  An easy cheat would be to set its position to xmax-100 or so rather than xmax (same for ymax).  Realistic bouncing is a lot more work though.  And you're still using the wrong sensor-  you're using the sensor that tells you portrait or landscape, not the accelerometer at all.

Comment: Here I found a nice solution.

http://xiangchen.wordpress.com/2011/12/17/an-android-accelerometer-example/